# Are these model\formulation the same?

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, integer-programming

For an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, the Vertex Coloring Problem is assigning a color to each vertex, such  that colors on adjacent vertices are different and the number of colors used is minimized.
One model for this problem is:

If we directly
assign each vertex a color (i.e.  define an integer variable $ x_i \forall i \in [1,|V|]$  then we need to ensure that adjacent neighbors are assigned different integers (i.e. $ x_i\neq x_j \forall i\neq j$ such that $i$ is neoghbor of $j$ ).
We can linearize these constraints by defining another binary variables $\delta_{i,j}$, and the final model is:

\begin{array}{rlc}{\textstyle\text{minimize}}\hspace{1em}&z&
\\[3pt]{\textstyle\text{subject to}}\hspace{1em}&x_i-x_j \ge 1-|V|\delta_{i,j} \hspace{1em}&\forall i,j \in E\\[3pt]&
x_i-x_j \le -1+|V| (1-\delta_{i,j}) \hspace{1em}&\forall i,j \in E\\[3pt]&
z\ge x_i \hspace{1em}&\forall i\in V \\[3pt]&
x_i\in \{1,...,|V|\}\hspace{1em}&\forall i\in V \\[3pt]&
\delta_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}\hspace{1em}&\forall i,j\in E \\[3pt]& z\ge0
\end{array}

Can we avoid using variable $z$ and constraints $z\ge x_i \ \ \forall i$? Is it correct If we define the objective function like the following.

\begin{array}{rlc}{\textstyle\text{minimize}}\hspace{1em}&\sum_{i=1}^{|V|}x_i&
\\[3pt]{\textstyle\text{subject to}}\hspace{1em}&x_i-x_j \ge 1-|V|\delta_{i,j} \hspace{1em}&\forall i,j \in E\\[3pt]&
x_i-x_j \le -1+|V| (1-\delta_{i,j}) \hspace{1em}&\forall i,j \in E\\[3pt]&
x_i\in \{1,...,|V|\}\hspace{1em}&\forall i\in V \\[3pt]&
\delta_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}\hspace{1em}&\forall i,j\in E 
\end{array}

How can I prove or reject the equality of these two formulation?

Comment: I think the right side of the first constraint in both your formulations should be $1-\vert V\vert \delta_{i,j}$ rather than  $1+\vert V\vert \delta_{i,j}$.

Comment: Also, the domain of $x_i$ should be either $\lbrace 0,\dots,\vert V\vert -1\rbrace$ or $\lbrace 1,\dots,\vert V \vert \rbrace$. You only need at most $\vert V\vert$ colors.

Comment: Hi @purbin you're absolutely right thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not solve the vertex coloring problem. Consider the tree consisting of an edge $ab$, a lot of vertices $x_i$ connected to $a$ and a lot of vertices $y_i$ connected to $b$. Then the sum-minimizing formulation will choose to color all of $x_i$ and $y_i$ with color $1$ and $a,b$ with colors $2,3$.

Comment: Hi. @Michal Adamaszek , I didn't understand it. In your example, after solving the model we have $\max=3$ and this is the #colors

Comment: @yaodaovang But the graph is a tree, so it is 2-colorable.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks a lot @Michal Adamaszek I've been thinking about a proof for days. Thanks again!